# How to delete bitnami moodle docker container completely?

Tags: docker, mariadb, moodle, bitnami

I have a problem, I cannot install any new Docker containers because of bitnami-moodle. I installed the bitnami-moodle container via Kitematic and then removed it. Now I cannot install any other Docker containers.
I already uninstalled Docker and performed a clean install.  The removal of bitnami-moodle and the MariaDB container was not successfully; they always reload onto the computer.

I have no idea how to stop bitnami-moodle and MariaDB from reloading. Maybe someone can help? Thanks in advance.

Below are my logs:

```
Sirkkas-MacBook-Pro:blaaaa sirkka$ docker-compose up
Recreating sirkka_mariadb_1 ... done
Recreating sirkka_moodle_1  ... error


ERROR: for sirkka_moodle_1  Cannot start service moodle: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sirkka_moodle_1 (d0689291c7c01a466816896e08e5bd11e0b9ffc988382d085cc01124cbda4066): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated'

ERROR: for moodle  Cannot start service moodle: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sirkka_moodle_1 (d0689291c7c01a466816896e08e5bd11e0b9ffc988382d085cc01124cbda4066): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Please add the contents of your docker-compose file and also run `docker ps -a` and paste the output hee

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that port 80 on your machine is already taken.

if you wish to remove the moodle container you can easily run: `docker rm -f $(docker ps | grep moodle | awk '{ print $1 }')`. but you should check for additional containers that might be mapped to port 80 (run `docker ps -a`), or maybe something on the host machine (go to Activity Monitor on your mac and see if there is an application that is using port 80).

It would be very easy to help you if you attach the contents of your docker-compose file and the output of `docker ps -a`

Comment: thanks, I will add the content of docker-compose file and docker ps.

Comment: @Sirkka was this answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the containers with "docker-compose up", try "docker-compose down". That will remove the resulting containers, cleanly. If you have to repeat, the correct sequence is "docker compose-down && docker compose up."